# Have DB users share tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to have 2 users of the DB (`user_app` and `user_migration`), one for executing migrations (which will have more privileges, like creating/dropping tables + basic usages) and one that the overlaying application will use to interact with the DB (which will have `select, insert, update, delete` privileges only).

The problem right now, that I'm facing, is that when I create a table from `user_migration`, the other user doesn't have the permissions to access that table.

This is the SQL code I've got for creating the users:

```
-- create the role
DO
$body$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles
      WHERE rolname = 'app_users')
  THEN

    CREATE ROLE "app_users";
  END IF;
END
$body$;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE :dbname TO "app_users";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "public" TO "app_users";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO "app_users";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO "app_users";

-- create the users and grant them role privileges
DO
$body$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
      WHERE usename = 'user_app')
  THEN

    CREATE USER "user_app" WITH PASSWORD 'somepswd';
    GRANT app_users TO user_app;
  END IF;

  IF NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
      WHERE usename = 'user_migration')
  THEN

    CREATE USER "user_migration" WITH PASSWORD 'somepswd';
    GRANT app_users TO user_migration;
  END IF;
END
$body$;

-- here, assign additional privileges to user_migration to create/delete entities
```

How can I set up the roles/users in order to achieve the described scenario above?

Comment: Who are you executing the above code as?  Since one of the steps is to create the role user_migration, you must not be be executing it as user_migration.  In which case, the default privileges you set up are applied to the wrong role.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you didn't run this script as `user_migration`, but as a different user.

Then the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements won't have the desired effect.

You should write:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user_migration IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO "app_users";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user_migration IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO "app_users";
```

Without the `FOR ROLE user_migration`, it will only affect tables created by the user that executed the statement.

Answer (score -2):

You need to grant the second user access to the first user's tables, or grant the relevant access to PUBLIC. Two users can't see each other's objects by default, it must be expressly permitted.

Read this:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: Let's say I want to grant SIUD of `user_migration`'s tables to `user_app`.
I could not find any command that would satisfy a hypothetical query like `grant ... on all tables of user/role "user_migration" to "user_app`.

Comment: @Milkncookiez `create role user_app login password '***' in role user_migration;` or for existing role `grant user_migration to user_app;`

Comment: That does not answer the question why the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` isn't working as expected.